# Is there a Pay or Open Source World Map web widget that is larger than 440x220 and allows the water to be black?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, world-map, google-visualization

For a project I just completed, I needed to show the winning selection of a poll in each country.  Ultimately we used **Google Charts API**, because the other Google World Map products did not allow the color of the water to be customized.  In this project the **water needs be black** so it blends with the web page it's on.  **The only problem with the Charts API version is that it's max size is 440x220.**

I've been searching the internet for a while and I've been unable to find a better, larger more customizable World Map product.

Is there a larger than 440x220 World Map product, for pay or open source, that allows me to set the color of the water so that it blends seamlessly with the web page it's on?

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenStreetMap project](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has both web and application map producers, and you have no restriction on the size of the display map nor on the styline.  Check out [their wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) to get you started.

If you like the offerings by Google in general, have you seen the option for a [maps visualization](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/topic.py?topic=27020) using [Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/)?  Also, there is a [May blog posting describing using Fusion Tables with dynamic styling](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/05/turn-up-power-of-your-fusion-tables.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20GoogleGeoDevelopersBlog%20%28Google%20Geo%20Developers%20Blog%29) that could be relevant.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a setting on OpenStreetMap that allowed me to set the color of the water to black.  Do you know for certain that one can change the water color on that OpenStreetMap?  Also, I think the maps visualization and Fusion tables had a similar problem, and it also reported tooltip heat values when it should not.

Comment: Nevermind [this link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/SketchyKosmosRules#Water_Features) might let me change the water color on OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool to create SVG maps : [Make a clickable map](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com) which also has a world map 
that you can customize to your liking: [Create a world map using Makeaclickablemap](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com/world)

Hope this will help you or any other folks who are after a customizable world map!